# Custom sort for String with 3 set of values in datatables

Tags: sorting, datatables

I have used datables on one of my html tables. There are multiple columns currenltly in it.
One of the columns in it can contain one of the below three values:

1. Amber
2. Pending
3. Red

I want to implement sorting such that all rows with value Pending are seen first, then Amber and then Red. (Cannot use the default ascending and descending sorting as the order will not be correct then)

code Snippet:

JSP (Table creation)

```
<table class="tableContent nofx cell-border compact" id="violationTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="col1"><i18n:message key="rule.name" /></th>
                <th class="col2"><i18n:message key="rule.value" /></th>                             
                <th class="col3"><i18n:message key="rule.isr.value" /></th>
                <th class="col4"><i18n:message key="rule.status" /></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <c:forEach items="${ruleViolationList}" var="i" varStatus="loopStatus">
                <tr data-rule-id="<c:out value="${i.id}" />" data-country-id="<c:out value="${i.countryId}" />"                 
                >
                    <td class="col1">
                        <c:out value="${i.PolicyRule}" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="col2">
                        <c:out value="${i.RuleValue}" escapeXml="false" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="col3">
                        <c:out value="${i.isrValue}" />
                    </td>
                    <c:choose>
                        <c:when test="${i.violationTypeId == 1}">
                            <td class="red status" >
                                <i18n:message key="rule.violation.red" />
                            </td>
                        </c:when>
                        <c:when test="${i.violationTypeId == 2}">
                            <td class="amber status" >
                                <i18n:message key="rule.violation.amber" />
                            </td>
                        </c:when>
                        <c:when test="${i.violationTypeId == 4}">
                            <td class="blue status" >
                                <i18n:message key="rule.violation.dispensation.approval.pending" />
                            </td>
                            </c:when>
                            <c:when test="${i.violationTypeId == 5}">
                                <td class="amber status" >
                                    <i18n:message key="rule.violation.amber" />
                                </td>
                            </c:when>
                            <c:when test="${i.violationTypeId == 6}">
                                <td class="red status" >
                                    <i18n:message key="rule.violation.red" />
                            </td>
                            </c:when>
                    </c:choose>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Servlet:

```
ArrayList<RuleViolation> ruleViolationList = daoFactory.getRuleViolationsDAO().list();       
request.setAttribute("ruleViolationList", ruleViolationList);
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#violationTable').DataTable();
});
```

So what i ideally want is, when the table is shown on page the data should be sorted alphabetically based on data in first column as well as data in last column (i.e Pending, Amber and then Red).

Comment: The answer would depend whether you're using client-side or server-side processing. Please show your DataTables initialization code.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com , the Servlet passes array of objects to jsp and then those are iterated to created rows in tables.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the snippet, you can highly customize how your column is filtered/sorted using the option [`columns.render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render).

The example I gave is not the smartest, but gives you one idea of what you can make. I advice you to use ["Nested Object data"](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/deep.html) if you choose this approach.

```js
var dataSet = [
  ['Name1', 3, 'Red'],
  ['Name2', 2, 'Amber'],
  ['Name3', 1, 'Pending']
];

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [
            { title: "Name" },
            { title: "Value" },
            { 
              title: "Types",
              "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
                if (type == 'sort') {
                  if (data == 'Red') return 3;
                  else if(data == 'Pending') return 1;
                  else if(data == 'Amber') return 2;
                } else {
                  return data;
                }
               }
            }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" width="100%"></table>
```

Comment: thanks for the above code, it definately helps. I have updated the question with the jsp and servlet code as well. Can you have a look and let me know you view